# Итератор для бинарного дерева (поиск следующего по возрастанию числа)

Tags: java, бинарное-дерево, итераторы

Мне необходимо сделать итератор для бинарного дерева. Как найти первое, меньшее число это понятно, но проблема в том, что число идущее прямо за ним по возрастанию, может оказаться довольно далеко от последнего.

Помогите придумать алгоритм обхода этого дерева на Java. Просьба не отсылать меня к ответам на C++ так как я совсем его не знаю.

Comment: Сортировка по возрастанию и получение 2-го элемента?

Comment: @Сергей Грушин да мне надо получить элементы по возрастанию - это основная задача. А второе число, потому что если найду второе, то и остальные тоже...

Comment: Вам надо отсортировать массив? Или что?

Comment: Вам нужен симметричный (in-order) обход дерева: сначала рекурсивно идем в левое поддерево, затем возвращаем текущий узел, затем идем в правое поддерево. Такой обход бинарного дерева поиска возвращает узлы в порядке возрастания. Вот тут пример: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12850889/in-order-iterator-for-binary-tree

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
     // Скомпилируйте и введите java TreeSort
    class Tree {
   public Tree left;            // левое и правое поддеревья и ключ
   public Tree right;
   public int key;

   public Tree(int k) {        // конструктор с инициализацией ключа
      key = k;
   }

/*  insert (добавление нового поддерева (ключа))
    сравнить ключ добавляемого поддерева (К) с ключом корневого узла (X).
    Если K>=X, рекурсивно добавить новое дерево в правое поддерево.
    Если K<X, рекурсивно добавить новое дерево в левое поддерево.
    Если поддерева нет, то вставить на это место новое дерево
*/
   public void insert( Tree aTree) {
     if ( aTree.key < key )
        if ( left != null ) left.insert( aTree );
        else left = aTree;
     else
        if ( right != null ) right.insert( aTree );
        else right = aTree;
   }

/*  traverse (обход)
    Рекурсивно обойти левое поддерево.
    Применить функцию f (печать) к корневому узлу.
    Рекурсивно обойти правое поддерево.
*/
   public void traverse(TreeVisitor visitor) {
      if ( left != null) 
            left.traverse( visitor );

      visitor.visit(this);

      if ( right != null ) 
            right.traverse( visitor );
   }
}

interface TreeVisitor {
  public void visit(Tree node);
};

class KeyPrinter  implements TreeVisitor {
  public void visit(Tree node) {
      System.out.println( " " + node.key );
  }
};

class TreeSort {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
     Tree myTree;
     myTree = new Tree( 7 );       // создать дерево (с ключом)
     myTree.insert( new Tree( 5 ) );  // присоединять поддеревья
     myTree.insert( new Tree( 9 ) );
     myTree.traverse(new KeyPrinter());
    }
    }
```

Источник: [Вики](https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D1%81_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E_%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B0)

Answer (score 2):

Прямой,обратный и концевой обходы

```
public void Pre(TreeVisitor visitor) {
    visitor.visit(this);
    if ( left != null)
        left.Pre( visitor );
    if ( right != null )
        right.Pre( visitor );
}
public void In(TreeVisitor visitor) {
    if ( left != null)
        left.In( visitor );
    visitor.visit(this);
    if ( right != null )
        right.In( visitor );
}
public void Post(TreeVisitor visitor) {
    if ( left != null)
        left.Post( visitor );
    if ( right != null )
        right.Post( visitor );
    visitor.visit(this);
}
```